# php sum count and retain multidimensional array

Tags: php

How do I sum up a multidimensional array and retain the fields and add a sum field. I like to sum up the field count.

the array looks like this:

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [landingpage_id] => 5305bc90b7a6bb56478b4581
        [offer_id] => 9233440331d06b1f22dadb1641007585
        [count] => 5
    )

[2] => Array
    (

        [landingpage_id] => 5305bc90b7a6bb56478b4581
        [offer_id] => 53146a8bb7a6bb9b688b4567
        [count] => 3
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [landingpage_id] => 5305bc90b7a6bb56478b4581
        [offer_id] => 53146a8bb7a6bb9b688b4567
        [count] => 2
    )
)
```

ideal results would be, since it would sum the count field with the unique com:

```
[0] => Array
    (
       [landingpage_id] => 5305bc90b7a6bb56478b4581
        [offer_id] => 9233440331d06b1f22dadb1641007585

        [count] => 5
    )



[1] => Array
    (
       [landingpage_id] => 5305bc90b7a6bb56478b4581
                [offer_id] => 53146a8bb7a6bb9b688b4567

        [count] => 5
    )
```

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: sorry was fixing the question. I keep getting disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$result = array_reduce($myArray, function ($carry, $item) {

    $key = $item['landingpage_id'] . $item['offer_id'];

    if (isset($carry[$key])) {
       $carry[$key]['count'] += $item['count'];
    } else {
       $carry[$key] = $item;
    }

    return $carry;

}, array());

$result = array_values($result); // this is needed only if you want to reset the keys of the resulted array
```

Comment: for some reason this outputs, almost same as the parameter

Comment: What do you mean?